# Codeigniter+Angular Js: How to use partials?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, partials

**This is the situation:**

I am building an app with Codeigniter + Angular Js.

Right now it is a simple app that grab some data from a database and display it in a table.
To build the app further i need to put the list inside a partial folder, but i am not able to load the file that need to be included.

**This is the question:**

How can i use partials in a Codeigniter + Angular Js project?
Where i need to put the partials folder?

**This is the code:**

The file index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <script src="assets/js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Codeigniter + Angular Js App</h1>
    <div class="main col-md-12"  ng-view></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The partial file list.html:

```
<section>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td><a href="#/user/{{user.user_id}}">{{user.name}}</a></td>
      <td>{{user.year}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</section>
```

This is the file app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'userControllers',
]);


myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
});
```

}]);

The file controllers.js:

```
var userControllers = angular.module('userControllers',[]);

  userControllers.controller('ListController',['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) 
{
      // Initialising the user array.
      $scope.users = [];

      // Getting the list of users through ajax call.
      $http({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/Angular/4-SampleApp2/main/json_get_users',
        method: "POST",
      }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.users= data;
  });
}]);
```

Right now the 'partials' folder is inside the 'views' folder, and inside there is one file: list.html

The table with the list of users is not loaded anymore.
Someone knows how can i load partials into a Codeigniter+Angular project?
Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

**This is the error message in the console:**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `http://127.0.0.1/Angular/4-SampleApp2/partials/list.html`

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess that would redirect the partial's request to index.php? (Let's say, if your .htaccess does not ignore .html files for example.)

Comment: Right now there is a .htaccess file inside the 'views' folder. I think is a codeigniter default file. The content is: Deny from all. I did not create any other .htaccess and inside the folder partials there is no .htaccess file.

Comment: Have you resolved this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$routeProvider.
when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
});
```

Comment: I have tried. Copying the file in the 'views' folder, but it seems is not working. Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you do the console log of $scope.users in browser? See if list.html not dispaly at all or just ng-repeat thing?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I have edited the question including the error message in the console

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have all site inside a subfolder */ci22*, so this is what I did (works like a charm):

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/adminpanel_controller', {
        templateUrl: 'ci22/adminpanel_view.php',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
      })
      .when('/ci22/categorias_controller', { 
        templateUrl: '/ci22/categorias_controller', 
        controller: 'Categoriasv2Controller'
      })
      .when('/ci22/idiomas_controller', { 
        templateUrl: '/ci22/idiomas_controller', 
        controller: 'IdiomasController'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

Comment: does the html5mode working when you refresh the page on your secondhand routes? i mean, not on your 'on-load' routes.

Answer (score 0):

#### First of all, make sure the folder path is correct

for my project, as I used codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc
my partials are under my modules' views folder

i.e
/project/application/modules/mymodule/views/list.html

Then I can use

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/list', {
      templateUrl: '<?=base_url()."mapplication/modules/".$this->router->fetch_module();?>/views/list.html',
      controller: 'ListController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/list'
    });
});
```

#### As codeigniter forbidden the direct access of the application directory, you may need to create a .htaccess to allow the angularjs routeProvider to load in the files.

In my case, I created a .htaccess

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

under modules directory

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to get AngularJS routing to work through Codeigniter's partial folder:**

1. Go to application > controllers
2. Inside the controllers folder, create a Partials.php file with the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Partials extends CI_Controller {

     public function view($view)
     {
         $this->load->view('partials/'.$view);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Go to applications > config > routes.php and add this code at the bottom

   ```
   $route['partials/(:any)'] = "partials/view/$1";
   ```
4. Finally, setup your route.js file assuming you have your app.js file setup with the var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

   ```
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/list', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/list.html', 
            controller: 'ListController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/list'
        });
    }]);
   ```

Comment: whoa dude! this question is three years old! thanks anyway :) If you are in the mood of answering you can check the latest questions for a selected tag as 'php' or 'angularjs'. People would be much more in need of help!